# Best Fit memory allocation C++

Tags: c++, memory, allocation

I'd like to create a best fit memory allocation solution.

```
int main()
{
    int input;
    int memoryBlock[ARRAY_SIZE] = {5, 10, 3, 9, 7};
    int bestFit;

    cout << "Please enter the memory size you want to allocate: ";
    cin >> input;

    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++){

        if (memoryBlock[i] - input < 0 ){

        }
        else {
            bestFit = memoryBlock[i];
        }

    }
    cout << bestFit;
}
```

Based on the above code, how can I modify it such that the `else {}` will select the closest number to it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code so that it only replaces the bestFit if it is smaller than it better:

```
int bestFit = -1;

for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i) {
    if (memoryBlock[i] - input >= 0 && memoryBlock[i] < bestFit) {
        bestFit = memoryBlock[i];
    }
}
```